# Why does vim work if command file is double clicked, but not from DOS?

Tags: microsoft-windows, vimscript-python, cmdline

(Windows7-64bits-Vim8.1)
I have a problem with getting the python in Vim to work. This problem is probably caused because I do not have admin access to the machine; I can't help that.

In order to narrow down the problem, I got it down to a one line cmd script that does work when double clicked, but not when started from DOS.
The script is:

```
<path to my home>\bin\Vim\vim81\gvim.exe
```

If I start this by double clicking, I get a perfectly fine gvim window, and it allows me to say

```
:py3 print("Hello")
```

Now if I start the very same file from DOS, it doesn't work: the same command :py print("Hello") gives E370 and E263.
The same works for every other way I could think of to start vim from DOS: starting from different directories, using start, using cmd, even using it with %edit in IPython.

I checked all environment variables, I checked the startup sequence of Vim, but I cannot see any difference. Except for the fact that Python3 works in only one of the cases.
By the way: my _vimrc (which is run in both cases) does modify pythonthreedll to the proper value, because I cannot get python in the registry.
What is going on? I am getting mad...

Comment: are you sure, it is the same gvim? Check the output of `:version` and `:echo v:progpath`

Comment: Yep, they give pixel-perfect identical information. The only difference I can see is the result of :py3 print; that is <nothing> versus <E370> and <E263>.
However, inspired by this I just found something else that is different
:echo $PATH gives different output. So now all I have to do  is finding the proper entry in $PATH that does the job. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I narrowed it down completely: even though I explicitly set the pythonthreedll variable, and the pythonthreehome, I still need to have python3 home dir in my $PATH. Weird. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: That is perfectly reasonable to need python in your $PATH, don't think this is a bug.

Comment: After trying out every possibility, I found that the setting of pythonthreehome has no effect, while $PATH does. Why is there a pythonthreehome then?

Comment: Not sure, might be a bug. What version is this? I think you should create an issue about it.